# How do I consolidate migrations using EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have these migrations:

```
00000000000000_First
20161101000000_Foo
20161102000000_Bar
// ...many many MANY more
20161108000000_Baz
```

I want to consolidate from `Foo` to `Baz` into one new migration. I know how to do that in EF, but not in EF Core.

I tried this:

```
dotnet ef update database 00000000000000_First
// delete all other migration classes
dotnet ef migrations add Consolidated
dotnet ef update
```

I expect that the new `Consolidated` migration will contain all changes to the model. But its `Up()` and `Down()` methods are empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found a hacky solution: manually edit the `ContextModelSnapshot` class, to remove all the new stuff, then add the consolidated migration. But there must be a better way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing one step. Because of the new model snapshot, after you manually delete the migration files, you'll need to run `dotnet ef migrations remove` (or `Remove-Migration` in PMC) to get it back in sync.

Instead of manually deleting the files, you could also just run `dotnet ef migrations remove` multiple times, but it's smart enough to detect manually deleted migrations.

Comment: I don't follow, my first step is to rollback the db to the first migration - `dotnet ef update database First`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean `dotnet ef migrations remove`

Answer (score 2):

EF Core, when executing `ef migrations add`, does NOT look into real database. Only your code (and DB model snapshot in `Migrations` folder) is used.

So, you need remove migrations from your migrations folder (using `dotnet ef migrations remove` multiple times) and then create consolidated using `ef migrations add`.

About your real database - if you want to roll it back too, you should run `ef database update XXX` before removing migrations. Or, if you are collapsing all migrations - you can simple drop database completely and then recreate from new migration(s).

Comment: I understand now, thanks. By the way according to @bricelam migrations are "smart enough to detect manually deleted migrations" so maybe you don't even need to run `remove` and just delete the migration files.